# How to enable / use new video / audio / images widgets in WordPress 4.8?

Tags: widgets

I've read [here](https://wordpress.org/news/2017/06/evans/) that you can now add video widgets, but I cannot see the option on my Widgets page. Can anyone advise how to enable/use it?

Comment: They don't show up in the "Available Widgets" section on your 4.8 install?

Comment: @birgire I've noticed that some others have this problem too. They can't find the new widgets in 4.8. Probably a bug?

Comment: Wonder if the same happens without any plugins activated and with the default theme? Anything in the error logs?